# Fill a vector xml path with radial color shade

Tags: xml, colors, path, fill

I want to know if there is a chance to fill a path with a radial color shade in an XML-drawable.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
vector android:height="64.0dip" android:width="64.0dip" android:viewportWidth="64.0" android:viewportHeight="64.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

path android:fillColor="#ff2196f3" android:pathData="M 64.07531,31.855837 A 32.037655,32.037655 0 0 1 32.037655,63.893492 32.037655,32.037655 0 0 1 0,31.855837 32.037655,32.037655 0 0 1 32.037655,-0.18181801 32.037655,32.037655 0 0 1 64.07531,31.855837 Z" android:strokeWidth="1.0"

  group android:translateX="9.0" android:translateY="6.0"

   path android:fillColor="#ffffffff" android:pathData="M20.4,18.0"

   path android:fillColor="#ffffffff" android:pathData="M42.0,32.0l0.0,-4.0L26.0,18.0L26.0,7.0c0.0,-1.7 -1.3,-3.0 -3.0,-3.0c-1.7,0.0 -3.0,1.3 -3.0,3.0l0.0,11.0L4.0,28.0l0.0,4.0l16.0,-5.0l0.0,11.0l-4.0,3.0l0.0,3.0l7.0,-2.0l7.0,2.0l0.0,-3.0l-4.0,-3.0L26.0,27.0L42.0,32.0z"

  /group

/vector>
```

The first path is the background circle that I want to fill with a radial color shade, I can fill it with a solid color only until now..I haven't found anything on the web...Can you help me please?

ANSWER: I found the answer [here](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/vector-graphics-in-android-converting-svg-to-vectordrawable/)

**VectorDrawable does not support gradients below api 24**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the SDK Documentation: [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)

**android:fillColor**
Specifies the color used to fill the path. May be a color or, for SDK 24+, a color state list or a gradient color (See [GradientColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#GradientColor) and [GradientColorItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#GradientColorItem)). If this property is animated, any value set by the animation will override the original value. No path fill is drawn if this property is not specified.

**android:strokeColor**
Specifies the color used to draw the path outline. May be a color or, for SDK 24+, a color state list or a gradient color (See [GradientColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#GradientColor) and [GradientColorItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#GradientColorItem)). If this property is animated, any value set by the animation will override the original value. No path outline is drawn if this property is not specified.

[VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)

Comment: so what's the answer? can't use a gradient?